# CellEditorListener calls the getCellEditorValue method when focusgained for a column in jtable

Tags: java, swing

I have a method that is used to store the edited values in the DB.

```
public Object getCellEditorValue() {
    String outputToCell = ((JTextField) component).getText();
    panelsign.updateAllergicReactions(outputToCell, row);
    return outputToCell;
}
```

This method is called by this method in JTable.class(pre-defined java class).

```
/**
 * Invoked when editing is finished. The changes are saved and the
 * editor is discarded.
 * <p>
 * Application code will not use these methods explicitly, they
 * are used internally by JTable.
 *
 * @param  e  the event received
 * @see CellEditorListener
 */
public void editingStopped(ChangeEvent e) {
    // Take in the new value
    TableCellEditor editor = getCellEditor();
    if (editor != null) {
        Object value = editor.getCellEditorValue();
        setValueAt(value, editingRow, editingColumn);
        removeEditor();
    }
}
```

The first mentioned method is called if I just click the row in the `JTable`. But I want it to be called after I complete editing it. Or like after editing it and then navigate to next column to edit that one.

Answer (score 2):

You should not be playing with the cell editor.

If you want to know when data have been changed in the TableModel you can either:

1. Override the `setValueAt(...)` method of your TableModel to update the database, or
2. Add a `TableModelListener` to the `TableModel`. An event will be generated whenever updates to the TableModel are made.

Comment: Glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark (beside the answer) so people know the problem has been solved.